# помощь в корректироке кода Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, while, break

Представь, что мы пишем программу для банковских карточек. Человек может совершать покупки, пока у него на карте хватает на это денег. 
В начале программы вводим количество денег, а потом вводим расходы, пока они не превышают баланс на карте. 
Когда превысили, мы должны получить, сколько успели сделать покупок и сколько осталось денег на карте.

Это мой код, вроде все правильно, но в конце цикла не суммирует последнюю покупку.

```
a = int(input("Введите сумму пополнения:"))
b = int(input("Введите сумму покупки:"))
n = 0

while (a-b)>0:
    a-=b
    n += 1
    b=int(input("Введите сумму покупки:"))

print(a,n)
```

вот результат

```
Введите сумму пополнения:100
Введите сумму покупки:20
Введите сумму покупки:20
Введите сумму покупки:20
Введите сумму покупки:20
Введите сумму покупки:20
20 4
```

Comment: значит ввод суммы покупки нужно ставить в начало цикла и убрать ввод вне цикла.

Comment: не получается, выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ты изначально запрашиваешь оплату покупки и в цикле сразу же делаешь это повторно? то есть сам цикл у тебя отрабатывает 4 раза изначально, по пробуй использовать пока А больше 0 что бы твоя программа работала пока у тебя на счету вообще есть деньги и сделай условие выхода с цикла.

Пример:

```
a = int(input("Введите сумму пополнения:"))
n,i = 0,0
while i<1:
    b = int(input("Введите сумму покупки:"))
    a-=b
    n += 1
    temp=input("Продолжить покупки?")
    if(temp=="" or temp=="Y"or temp=="y"or temp=="Да"or temp=="да"):
        i=0
    else:
        i=1
print(a,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = int(input("Введите сумму пополнения: "))
n = 0

while True:
    b = int(input("Введите сумму покупки: "))
    if a-b > 0:
        a -= b
        n += 1
    else:
        break

print(f'\nСовершено покупок: {n} \nБаланс на карте: {a}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы хотите что бы в конце выводился остаток баланса и количество покупок:

```
Balance = int(input('Введите сумму пополнения: '))
CountOfPurchases = 0

while True:
    Price = int(input('Введите сумму покупки: '))
    Balance -= Price
    CountOfPurchases += 1
    if (Balance - Price) < 0:
        break

print(Balance, CountOfPurchases)
```

Если цена превышает баланс - программа прекращает свою работу

Comment: Спасибо большое. все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```py
from itertools import count
a = int(input("Введите сумму пополнения:"))
for n in count():
    if a <= 0:
        print("Вы не можете совершать покупки. До свидания!")
        break
    while True:
        b = int(input("Введите сумму покупки:"))
        if b > 0: break
        print("Неправильный ввод суммы покупки, повторите еще раз!")
    if a - b < 0:
        print("Сумма покупки превышает баланс. До свидания!!!")
        break
    a -= b
print("Баланс:", a, "Количество покупок:", n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (a-b)>0:
```

Проблема в том, что в конце у вас остаётся на счету 20, покупка тоже на 20, а проверяете вы, что `20-20>0`, т.е. `0>0` это условие не выполняется. Нужно проверять `>=` как-раз на случай, если последняя покупка будет ровно на всю оставшуюся сумму:

```
while (a-b)>=0:
```

Фактически, вы вашим текущим условием проверяете не условие "хватит ли у меня денег на эту покупку?", а "останется ли у меня хоть что-нибудь после очередной покупки?" Чтобы такое условие выполнилось, у вас должна остаться хотя бы одна копейка.